# Introductory book on Distribution theory

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, distribution-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distribution theory book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/distribution-theory-book)

Is there a good alternative to Friedlander *[Introduction to the Theory of Distributions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521649714)* ?
 Many thanks !