# Good references on Distribution Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, distribution-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distribution theory book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/distribution-theory-book)

Two books I have been reading are [Strichartz's A Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/A_Guide_to_Distribution_Theory_and_Fouri.html?id=T7vEOGGDCh4C&redir_esc=y) and PartII of [Rudin's Functional Analysis](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Sh_vAAAAMAAJ&q=Functional%20analysis%20Rudin&dq=Functional%20analysis%20Rudin&source=bl&ots=_T7iLsjCyu&sig=WzKMXFXHay1vM4StWwLaOT-ex2o&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=DONRUK2QNcqZiQeFl4CgAg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA) . Both are good books.

However, the problem I am facing is that Rudin is sometimes too compact for me. It is like the author is trying to hide as much as insight and motivation as possible, which is not a very appropriate approach to distributions since they are actually a very 'practical' tool whose value lies in its usefulness. On the other extreme, Strichartz is too intuitive. For instance he does not give a clear examination about the topology of test functions, let alone the space of distributions (*'At any rate, all functionals you will encounter are continuous'* p4).

I found it difficult to combine these two books. It would be helpful if there is some good reference that lies between these two extremes.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget that the topology of $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is rather hard to define. Either you are satisfied with the notion of convergent sequence, or you must study topological vector spaces.

Comment: (http://books.google.fr/books/about/Distributions_and_Operators.html?id=v7ydobPDBMgC&redir_esc=y)This is also a good reference.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate: there are at least 5 books in the linked thread beyond the two you mentioned in your question, the thread also links to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20314/good-books-on-theory-of-distributions which has a staggering 19 answers. If somehow none of those suggested books are at the right level; please edit the question and also ping me to re-open the question.

Comment: Note that Strichartz's book also has a section in the end on "Further readings". To give you a start on the many references in the links provided, maybe you want to start by check out Friedlander and Joshi, or perhaps Treves' _Topological vector spaces, distributions, and kernels_